# unable to create/drop user from postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to drop the user "theuser"

```
postgres-# \du
                          List of roles
    Role name  |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
    -------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
    postgres    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
    theuser | Create DB                                      | {}
postgres-# drop user theuser
postgres-# \du
                          List of roles
    Role name  |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
    -------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
    postgres    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
    theuser | Create DB
```

not really sure why it's not dropping the user?

same with creating a user

```
postgres-# create user bob with createdb login
postgres-# \du
                          List of roles
     Role name  |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
     -------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
     postgres    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
     sportstweet | Create DB
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to terminate the statement with a `;`, otherwise psql doesn't "see" that your statement is finished.

The prompt changed from `postgres=#` to `postgres-#` (`=` vs. `-`) to indicate that you are "inside" one statement, and not in the "next" one. A bit hard to see I admit. You can configure this display though, if you want a more visible distinction. For details please see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING

(Btw: if you have disabled auto-commit, you'll need to commit it as well!)